# Change Facebook Cover Picture with preview_cover on Android

Tags: android, facebook

I've a php application that allow you to change your Timeline Cover picture posting a photo to an album, and with the retrieved ID, redirects you to:

> http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?preview_cover=[photo_id]

Also, if you paste directly that link on your browser with a valid ID, it works perfectly.

But on android it does not. Even if I change to-

> http://**m**.facebook.com/profile.php?preview_cover=[photo_id]

What's the way to do this on android?

Answer (score 0):

In case others come across this -

I haven't found a way yet to change the cover photo image within the m.facebook.com environment.

You can, however, add **&ref=pb** to the end of the URL to force the Desktop experience in mobile.

This isn't ideal, but does allow the user to set their cover photo:

[http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?preview_cover=[photo_id]&ref=pb](http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?preview_cover=%5bphoto_id%5d&ref=pb)

If I come across a better implementation, I'll update this post.